error:lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
 error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
   34 |         scanf("%lf\n", &prompt_for_parking());

I have a prototype for it: double prompt_for_parking(void);
How can I debug this? I'm trying to have the user input a value in double and store it into prompt_for_parking.

Welcome to SO. A function is not a variable. How would you "store" anything in a function? You can pass a value to the function via a parameter but for that, you need a variable first.

There is another "error" in this short code, in the scanf() format string. Please see What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string? Every character in the format string has a specific purpose.

What exactly does the prompt_for_parking function do, and what are you doing after you call it?

prompt_for_parking is declared as a function.
To store in a variable:
// double prompt_for_parking(void);
double prompt_for_parking;

// scanf("%lf\n", &prompt_for_parking());
scanf("%lf\n", &prompt_for_parking);

Tip: check the return value of scanf().  Is it 1?
Tip: it's likely best to remove the trailing white-space.
// scanf("%lf\n", ...
scanf("%lf", ...


Your prompt_for_parking is declared as a function that takes no input parameters and returns a temporary double value. Taking the address of a temporary is not allowed, hence the compiler error. Nor does it make sense to do so in this context anyway.
The %lf specifier expects a pointer to a double variable instead, eg:
double prompt_for_parking;
scanf("%lf\n", &prompt_for_parking);


We could simulate the assignment of a value to a function, if it has access to a memory space outside itself (static variable or allocated on the heap).
#include <stdio.h>

double* fct(void)
{
    static double s_double;
    return &s_double;
}

int main(void)
{
    scanf("%lf", fct());
    printf("%f\n", *fct());

    return 0;
}

I'm not sure that's what you want to do.

You are trying to store something inside the address of the return value to the function rather than passing it as input to the function.
To explain the meaning of the error message gibberish:

Unary & refers to the address-of operator which is an unary operator since it only has one operand (to the right). There is also the bitwise AND operator &, same symbol but two operands, so that one is a binary operator. The compiler message says unary to distinguish between those two.
lvalue means an addressable memory location where data can be read/write accessed. The term originates from "left value of the = operator" since the left operand of the assignment operator is where you store something, but has gotten a broader meaning over the years. And the other way around: a rvalue ("right value") would be something that you cannot address or write to.

From there on we may note that the address-of operator requires an addressable memory location, an lvalue. (And similarly, the related indirection operator * will result in something which is an lvalue.)
When you have a function like int f (void), the result is stored in a temporary, unnamed memory location by the function. It could be a CPU register or a position on the stack - the compiler decides. CPU registers don't have addresses though, so probably for that reason the C language was designed so that you can't take the address of the return value from a function - it is not a lvalue, but rather a rvalue.
Similarly if we do something like a + b that result too is stored in a temporary location which we cannot write to or take the address of. &(a + b) gives a similar error as yours: "cannot take the address of an rvalue".

How to fix it:
I would kind of expect a function named prompt_for_parking to prompt the user, so moving the scanf into the function seems to be the correct design here. No matter where the scanf is located, you'll have to store the result in a named variable. Of type double in this case, since you use %lf.
One alternative would be to design the function as for example void some_function (double x); - taking a double parameter but returning no value. Then:
double tmp;
scanf("%lf", &tmp);
some_function(tmp);

Now how to do this in a real program of course depends on what that program is supposed to do.
